# how to get first event from user scroll action

Tags: rxjs

I'm not familiar with rxjs.
how can I first wheel event from single user wheel move action?

my idea is use debounceTime to get when user wheel action end and get first event from wheel event start to end.

how can I first wheel event from single user wheel move action?

Comment: are you using Angular or vanilla JS? have you already some code you can share?

Comment: @Zerotwelve I'm using react

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. This will log the first value coming from `wheel` event, but you can do anything you want in the subscription:

```
firstWheelEvent = fromEvent(document, 'wheel').pipe(first()).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I want get first wheel event for each user wheel action.

Comment: What do you mean by 'for each user wheel action'? What should the **different** wheel actions be? There is only one kind of wheel action event.

Comment: i think the idea with `debounceTime` is good. just change it to:
firstWheelEvent = fromEvent(document, 'wheel').pipe(debounceTime(100),first()).subscribe(console.log);

Comment: well, `debounceTime` isn't doing anything here other than changing the first emitted value, right? Let's say there are 10 wheel events happening, each 50ms apart. Then this would result in returning the 10th wheel event (100ms after the last wheel event). Maybe i am missing the actual point of the question but I don't know how the "end" of a wheel action should be defined.